# How to get address from latitude and longitude using angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular6, reverse-geocoding

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(pos => {
        x.value = "" + pos.coords.longitude;
        y.value = "" + pos.coords.latitude;

        this.locations.push({
          lng: pos.coords.longitude,
          lat: pos.coords.latitude,
          time: local.value,
          picture: picture.value,
          publicIp: publicIp.value,
          privateIp: privateIp.value
        });

        console.log(this.locations);

        console.log(local.value);
```

Comment: Use an third party API. For example [this Google one](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting the address from the latitude and longitude you will have to use some reverse geocoding API. Try searching for some free API which provides the same.

**ArcGIS provides a free (and paid) API:**

https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/geocode/api-reference/geocoding-reverse-geocode.htm

It provides an address for a given location (lat/lon). It doesn't even require an API key, but they suggest you get a free one to avoid rate limits.

Have fun implementing it :)

Comment: Hi Thank you for this, by the way I have my own API and I'm getting the longitude and latitude using <agm> but I'm really having a hard time to get the address using the long lat that I'm getting. :(

Comment: @Sed - Glad it worked for you. Please upvote the answer if it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a reverse geocoding API like the following:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse

Below an example from the link above:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Reverse Geocoding</title>
    <style>
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #floating-panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 25%;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
      }
      #floating-panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -180px;
        width: 350px;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
      }
      #latlng {
        width: 225px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="floating-panel">
      <input id="latlng" type="text" value="40.714224,-73.961452">
      <input id="submit" type="button" value="Reverse Geocode">
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 8,
          center: {lat: 40.731, lng: -73.997}
        });
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

        document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
          geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow);
        });
      }

      function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow) {
        var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
        var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
        var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]), lng: parseFloat(latlngStr[1])};
        geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
          if (status === 'OK') {
            if (results[0]) {
              map.setZoom(11);
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map
              });
              infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            } else {
              window.alert('No results found');
            }
          } else {
            window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, really appreciate it. I will try this one I hope this will work to me :)